# Spring framework, I need one variable to be session dependent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm making a simple file server application. The application is scanning the current location for files and show them to a user.

I need one variable, the current path to be session local. I want to avoid the situation when one user is changing directory to another user.

As is:

> *User1 is opening home page (current location Z:/), user1 is changing directory to Z:/foo, User2 is opening home page and he is home page is
>   Z:/foo.*

To be:

> *User1 is opening home page (current location Z:/), user1 is changing directory to Z:/foo, User2 is opening home page and he is home page is
>   Z:/, but User1 is still at Z:/foo*

I was trying to use `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

But either I made some failures (in coding) or it won't work for me

Comment: @Scope is the way to go. Paste actual usage code.

Comment: @Antoniossss https://github.com/Domis97/Simple_ftp <- whole repo. FileSystemStorageService and FileUploadController two most important.

Comment: And which class is supposed to be session scoped?

Comment: The best option would be variable private Path rootLocation from FileSystemStorageService which implements StorageService

Comment: Then put that `rootLocation` in `UserSpace` from my example, and `@Autowire` `UserSpace` into that service.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thank You for Your help, I'm going to inform You tomorrow if it works <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create separate, session scoped bean and inject it whenever you need session scoped data - even in application scoped beans. eg

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
public class UserSpace{

    private File userRoot=....somehow set that on bean creation - eg at @PostConstruct
   .....other fields if needed
}
```

and then

```
@Service
class YoutService{

  @Autowired
  private UserSpace userSpace;// this will be session scoped proxy

}
```

Comment: Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException


I tried to use getter and setter from UserSpace  in service but it didnt worked :/

Comment: Are you calling that from web controller? (you should) It will work only on web  call handling thread. For other processing in other threads you will have to pass the context, or (which is what I preffer) whole instance.

Comment: Thank You, for Your help. When I put UserSpace to controller Your solution worked.